# Archieve artificate is copies wrong artifacts

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins job which copies artifacts from another job using Copy Artifacts from another job configuration, when we run the job alone it copies latest successful build artifacts, however when we try to run it from up stream job it is wrongly copying artifacts

In both scenarios it should copy latest artifacts

Comment: could you share some more information about the job setup and how they are triggered? Ideally, the Job DSL for each job would really help to get a better idea of what might be causing this! ; )

Comment: @gsaslis have two project dependencies which are building individually and another job which is resposible to create a installer, installer job is copying dependency artifacts using "latestsuccessfuljob", the problem is one of dependecy artifacts are not copied over still it is taking old .inf file (meaning current version is .32 it is picking .27 version of .inf)

Comment: Sorry the issue is with the script that we are using is overwriting the existing copied files, funny issue not realized :)